# Query for an amount of days of data with SQLAlchemy DateTime field?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQlALchemy model with a `DateTime` field.

```
class MyModel(DeclarativeBase):
   created_at = Column(DateTime)
```

How can I go about querying for the latest upto 10 **days** of records? Is this possible with a DateTime field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```py
import datetime

start_time = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
# Assuming your object is called DBSession
# Might also be something like db.session
DBSession.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.created_at>=start_time)
```

Edit: I think this SQL query does what you are actually looking for, can you try if it works? If so we can probably convert it to sqlalchemy syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM my_model WHERE created_at IN (
  SELECT created_at FROM forms_formresponse 
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: That's the latest records within the last 10 days. I want the latest 10 full days of data from any timeframe

Comment: So you want to find the most recent entry and get all entries from 10 days before that one?

Comment: No, the most recent x actual days of records which exist in the table.

Not the most recent WITHIN x days.

Comment: can you check if my edit is closer to what you are looking for?